# Prove that frames are the sequences of the form $\left\{U e_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ where $U$ is a bounded surjective operator on $\mathcal{H}$.

Tags: operator-theory

Let us assume that $\left\{e_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

I would like to prove that frames are the sequences of the form $\left\{U e_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ where $U$ is a bounded surjective operator on $\mathcal{H}$.

Working on $U$ we know that orthonormal bases are the sequences of the form $\left\{U e_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ where $U$ is a unitary operator on $\mathcal{H}$ because:
$$\langle U e_j, U e_i\rangle=\langle e_j, e_i\rangle$$
by definition of a unitary operator.

The Riesz bases are instead the sequences of the form $\left\{U e_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ where $U$ is a bounded bijective operator on $\mathcal{H}$, directly by definition of Riesz basis.

It seems to me that the statement on the frame is a bit more difficult. Any suggestions, please?

**My attempt**
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle f, U e_k\right\rangle\right|^2=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle U^{*} f, e_k\right\rangle\right|^2=\left\|U^* f\right\|^2$$
But
$$\left\|U^* f\right\|^2\leq \left\|U^*\right\|^2 \left\|f\right\|^2=\left\|U\right\|^2 \left\|f\right\|^2\leq B\left\|f\right\|^2$$
because we know that $U$ is bounded. Moreover, $U$ is also surjective, thus we know that there exists a constant $A>0$ such that
$$\left\|U^* f\right\|^2\geq A \|f\|^2$$

Comment: Should not $U$ have also positive lower and upper bound?

Comment: No, I took it from the book by Ole Christensen, "An Introduction to Frames and Riesz Bases"

Comment: Anyway, I proposed now a possible proof, editing my post.